# Reading input through stdin using fgets error

Tags: c, stack, parentheses

For class, I have to write a code that checks for balanced parentheses. The input will be given through stdin (running it as: code.exe < in.txt)

The input is formatted like this:

```
CASE 1: (())
CASE 2: [})(
CASE n: ...
***end***
```

I coded it like this:

```
int main(void) {
    char test[200];
    char str[200];
    char end[] = "***end***";
    int caseNo = 1;
    int j;
    int flag;

    while(1) {
    if(strcmp(fgets(test, 200, stdin), end) == 0) {
        break;
    } else {
        strcpy(str, test);
        int len = strlen(str);
        for(int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
            if(str[i] == ':') {
                j = i + 2;
                break;
            }
        }

        flag = balanced_parenthesis(str, j);

        if(flag == 0) {
            printf("CASE %d: NOT BALANCED\n", caseNo);
        } else if(flag == 1) {
            printf("CASE %d: BALANCED\n", caseNo);
        }
        caseNo++;
    }
}
```

But, the output that comes out is wrong. I've already checked my balanced_parenthesis function separately, and it does work, which leads me to believe that the error is in reading the input.

Am I using fgets or strcmp wrong? Is there a better way to read the input?

---

Edit:

Full Code is shown here:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int top = -1;
char stack[200];

void push(char c) {
    top++;
    stack[top] = c;
}

char pop() {
    return(stack[top--]);
}

int pairs(char open, char close) {
    if(open == '(' && close == ')') {
        return 1;
    } else if (open == '[' && close == ']') {
        return 1;
    } else if (open == '{' && close == '}') {
        return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}

int balanced_parenthesis(char str[], int j) {
    int len = strlen(str);
    for(int i = j; i < len; i++) {
        if((str[i] == '(') || (str[i] == '[') || (str[i] == '{')) {
            push(str[i]);
        } 
        if((str[i] == ')') || (str[i] == ']') || (str[i] == '}')) {
            if(top == -1) { //empty
                return 0;
            } else {
                char temp = pop();
                if(pairs(temp, str[i]) == 0) {
                    return 0; //not pairs
                }
            }
        }
    }

    if(top == -1) {
        return 1; //balanced
    } else {
        return 0; //not balanced
    }
}

int main(void) {
    char test[200];
    char str[200];
    char end[] = "***end***";
    int caseNo = 1;
    int j;
    int flag;

    while(1) {
        if(fgets(test, 200, stdin) == NULL) {
            break;
        } else {
            test[strcspn(test, "\n")] = '\0';
            if(strcmp(test, end) == 0) {
                break;
            } else {
                strcpy(str, test);
                int len = strlen(str);
                for(int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
                    if(str[i] == ':') {
                        j = i + 2;
                        break;
                    }
                }

                flag = balanced_parenthesis(str, j);

                if(flag == 0) {
                    printf("CASE %d: NOT BALANCED\n", caseNo);
                } else if(flag == 1) {
                    printf("CASE %d: BALANCED\n", caseNo);
                }
                caseNo++;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Sample Input:

```
CASE 1: ([[]{()}])()
CASE 2: ()[]{}
CASE 3: (([[]))
CASE 4: (()}
CASE 5: (()()()())
CASE 6: (((())))
CASE 7: (()((())()))
CASE 8: ((((((())
CASE 9: ()))
CASE 10: (()()(()
CASE 11: ][
CASE 12: ({)}
***end***
```

Expected Output:

```
CASE 1: BALANCED
CASE 2: BALANCED
CASE 3: NOT BALANCED
CASE 4: NOT BALANCED
CASE 5: BALANCED
CASE 6: BALANCED
CASE 7: BALANCED
CASE 8: NOT BALANCED
CASE 9: NOT BALANCED
CASE 10: NOT BALANCED
CASE 11: NOT BALANCED
CASE 12: NOT BALANCED
```

Comment: You need to remove the trailing newline before comparing in `if(strcmp(fgets(test, 200, stdin), end) == 0) {`

Comment: Use `test[strcspn(test,"\n")]='\0'` to overwrite `'\n'`. and then do the comparison `strcmp(test,end)==0`. `break` after `return 0` is redundant.

Comment: I tried using strcspn like you suggested and I can now read the input without the '\n', however the output is still incorrect :/

Comment: Do you realise that `fgets` may return null?

Comment: I don't think I can post the problem link, sorry. And I'm currently reading the return type, and I added a statement to catch if fgets returns NULL, but it's still outputting the incorrect output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a logical flaw in your code:-

for every line that you wish to check - before that you must ensure to rest the state of the stack. That's what you didn't do which caused problem.

```
void stack_reset(){
    top = -1;
}
```

In `main()`

```
  ...
  if(strcmp(test, end) == 0) {
        break;
    } else {
        reset();
        strcpy(str, test);
        ...
```

This change will make your code work. Otherwise it was handling with previous state also.

As you have `\n` as input to the char array `test` your comparison fails.

Considering that your rest of the code is alright , there is a single change you need to do to make this work. (This is problem if there is `\n` at the end of the input file). It is still good to add this solution - that will make this solution work irrespective of newline at the last line of the file.

```
while(1) {
    if( !fgets(test, 200, stdin) ){
       /* error handling*/
    }
    test[strcspn(test,"\n")]='\0';
    if(strcmp(test, end) == 0) {
        break;
    } else {
        ...
```

You are overwriting the `\n` with the `\0` because `strcspn` returns the number of character read before it encounters any of the character specified in the second parameter to `strcspn`.

Also once `return` statement is executed there is no use of the `break` statement as control never reach that point. And you exit from the function.

```
            if(pairs(temp, str[i]) == 0) {
                return 0; //not pairs
                // break; <-- not needed.
            }
```

---

The way you took input won't fail when you have the input file ended with no newline. If there is then the last comparison with `***end***` will fail.

<sup>The reason behind making the `reset()` function separate from your `main()` module is that - if later you need to change the implementation of `stack` then the user code won't be affected.  It can still call the `reset()` and be sure that it will reset the state of the stack. Also as another suggestion, try not to make the stack variable `top` global, even better if you can pass the structure from function to function instead of using global one.</sup>